# Using V-flex within a V-Card not working as expected

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

So i have been attempting to create a V-Card in vuetify with a specific layout. The top part of the card will vary in size and therefore I need to be able to align the bottom part of the card to the bottom.

So i've tried to do the following code here which should allow the first part to "grow" to fill the height and then the second part to "shrink" and stay at the bottom...

However, no success.. I probably just have done something sligthly wrong here but I'm pulling out my hair...

Here is my code:

```
<v-card shaped color="white" height="100%" width="100%">
<v-container fluid>
  <v-layout column>
    <v-flex grow>
      {{ skinName }}
      <v-img :src="skinImage" />
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex shrink>
      <v-chip
        class="ma-2"
        color="indigo"
        text-color="white"
      >
        <img height="10px" src="~static/logo-icon.png"> {{ priceInCoins | decimalPlace }}
      </v-chip>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

[image]

As you can see from my image, the blue "coins" should all align at the bottom in the same place no matter how big the text is above it!

Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container is not filling the height of the card, so there is no 'empty space' for the flexbox to redistribute. You can use the [fill-height](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid) attribute on both the layout and the container element to make sure it stretches.

Comment: Wow, told you it would be something simple. Just needed a fresh pair of eyes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: heh, I've encountered this exact issue myself more often than I like to admit ;p